# How do I subscribe to multiple Observables individually and know when they are all finished?

Tags: rxjs-observables

I have come across a problem a few times now and I can't really figure out how to word it to get the answer I'm looking for on Google/SA so here goes.

I have multiple http observables. Lets say I want to delete object 1, 2 and 3. I send three http delete requests to `myapi/{id}` one after the other. I can subscribe to each request as each returns an Observable. This allows me to do something after each has completed or failed with `myHttpObservable.subscribe(successFn, failFn)`.

Heres where the problem comes in. I now want to know when all three delete requests have finished. To do this I can use `forkJoin([deleteRequest1, deleteRequest2, deleteRequest3]` but forkJoin takes an array of Observables and subscribes to them. I cannot subscribe to them individually now since `forkJoin` wants an array or Observables.

So how do I subscribe to each Observable with its own success and failure functions but also know when all three are done?

Answer (score 1):

The forkJoin will return the response of each observable in the same order your provided them. So for example, you have three observables

```
const source1$ = of("Observable 1");
const source2$ = of("Observable 2");
const source3$ = of("Observable 3");
```

You'll get the subscription of each in **forkJoin** like this

```
forkJoin([source1$, source2$, source3$]).subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
  console.log(res1);
  console.log(res2);
  console.log(res3);
});
```

Here is the [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-be1rnn?file=index.ts).

Thanks.